# Can I "count" the number of times a field/name in a json file occurs using python? I do not need the value in the field but the name occurrence

Tags: python, json, parsing, count

I have json in a text file that is formatted like so:

```
{  
   "_id":"123adfvssw",
   "content_type":"video",
   "content_id":"12345",
   "commenter":{  
      "display_name":"student2",
      "name":"student2",
      "type":"user",
   },
   "source":"chat",
   "state":"published",
   "message":{  
      "body":"the world",
      "fragments":[  
         {  
            "text":"the world"
         }
      ],
      "is_action":false
   },
   "more_replies":false
}
{  
   "_id":"123adfvssw",
   "content_type":"video",
   "content_id":"12345",
   "commenter":{  
      "display_name":"student",
      "name":"student",
      "type":"user",
   },
   "source":"chat",
   "state":"published",
   "message":{  
      "body":"the space",
      "fragments":[  
         {  
            "text":"the space"
         }
      ],
      "is_action":false
   },
   "more_replies":false
}
```

---

I would like to loop through the text file and count how many times the commenter field appears and save the results in another text file in the following format:

For Example:

FileName   Commenters    2

---

I have some code but am getting stuck when it comes to counting the occurrence of the field names and not their values.

```
import json
import  requests
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> filepath="/chatinfo.txt"
>>> with open(filepath) as f:
...     for line in f:
...             jsondata = json.loads(line)
...             dictjson = json.dumps(jsondata)
...             len(jsondata["commenter"])
```

However, len is counting the number of fields nested inside of the commenter field.

Can anyone give me an idea of what I can use to count the occurrence of the commenter field name and possibly set up an exception if the commenter field isn't present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
num_with_field = 0
for line in f:
    jsondata = json.loads(line)
    dictjson = json.dumps(jsondata)
    if "commenter" in jsondata:
        num_with_field += 1
```

The `in` keyword checks if the given dictionary contains the given key.

Writing the resulting file is left to you.

Comment: Is there a way to count commenter field name base on their unique id and/or name? For example, commenter student has 1 and the commenter student2 has 1. In all the post has 2 commenters. Essentially I would only want to count that commenter once even if they comment twice or more on one post.

Comment: Also, there is no purpose in calling `dictjson = json.dumps(jsondata)`, nor in calling the result `dictjson` when `dumps()` returns a string. You are just getting back the same JSON string you read in `line`.